# How to pass vm to a setTimeout in AngularJs? Changes to scope don't update DOM view

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, angularjs-scope, settimeout

I'm trying the following code. Everything seems to be working as I see the component appear/disappear depending on the value I set for the variable. However, when I do that in the `setTimeout(...)` function, it starts to misbehave. The *poofy* text shows but the value set to `vm` doesn't. My guess is that I need to pass it in somehow but I'm not sure how.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("Banana", banana);

  function banana() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.showStuff = false;

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("poof!");
      vm.showStuff = true;
    }, 1000);
  }
})();
```

Do I need to make the view-model globally accessible?

Comment: Why not use `$timeout` instead? Have you tried with it instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: you'll have to force a digest.

Comment: @DanielA.White "Force a digest"?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I got that working now, according to the answer below. Now, I'm curious why I had to do that...

Comment: @AndyJ `$timeout` calls `$rootScope.$digest()`.

Comment: `setTimeout` is a JavaScript native function, and not an AngularJS function per se. So when you use something outside the "Angular world" (like you were doing) you have to execute a `$scope.$apply()` in order to keep the Angular mechanism up to date. On the other hand `$timeout` is an AngularJS wrapper of `setTimeout` which already takes care of triggering all necessary mechanisms to "keep things up to date" in the "Angular world" like `$rootScope.$digest()` as @DanielA.White just said.

Comment: As @lealceldeiro is explaining you will need to use $apply(), I made an example so you can see it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the script bellow.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

     angular
         .module("app")
         .controller("Banana", banana);

     function banana($timeout) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.showStuff = false;

        $timeout(function () {
            console.log("poof!");
            vm.showStuff = true;
        }, 1000);
     }
})();
```

To be noted - there's additional step required.

1. Substitute `setTimeout(...)` for `$timeout(...)`.
2. Pass `$timeout` into `banana(...)`.
3. Provide `banana.$inject = ["$timeout",...]`.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I took the liberty to suggest an improvement. But still, I'd be nice to know a bit more about why I had to use a different function.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) method with setTimeout:

```
//WORKS
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply("vm.showStuff = true");
}, 1000);
```

OR use the AngularJS [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service:

```
//RECOMMENDED
$timeout(function () {
    vm.showStuff = true;
}, 1000);
```

The [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method creates an event outside the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. The [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) wraps `window.setTimeout` and integrates it with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

> Angular modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and Angular execution context. Only operations which are applied in Angular execution context will benefit from Angular data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc... You use [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to enter Angular execution context from JavaScript.
>
> Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.
>
> [image]
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Hey What Mateus Koppe is showing it's a good answer, I would like to extend, just because this can help someone that needs to apply changes to the view.

The $Timeout service on angular refreshes the data on the view, but with setTimeout you don't have the same effect, so you should use $scope and $apply() to force the refresh on the screen.

On my [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/moplin/x8mnwf5a/) I use them, to show you the effect.

```
    //Timeout angularjs
    $timeout(function () {
        console.log("poof! $timeout");
        vm.showStuff = true;
    }, 1000);

    //Tiemout regular
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("poof1! setTimeout");
      vm.showStuff1 = true;
    }, 1000);

    //Timeout + $scope.$apply
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("poof2! setTimeout");
      vm.showStuff2 = true;
      $scope.$apply();    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }, 3000);
```

I hope it helps.

As its explained on [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply())

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life-cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

Also you should avoid using on [$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)

> Usually, you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in
>   directives. Instead, you should call $apply() (typically from within a
>   directive), which will force a $digest().

Please check my example here.
https://jsfiddle.net/moplin/x8mnwf5a/

Answer (score 0):

As explained in previous answers it has to do with the $digest cycle, native `setTimeout()` doesn't trigger the digest cycle and therefore the view doesn't get re-rendered with new value of `vm.showStuff`.

I'd slightly extend [Pablo Palacious's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4584038/pablo-palacios) answer with the following usage of $scope.$apply(),

```
//Timeout + $scope.$apply
setTimeout(function () {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    console.log("poof2! setTimeout");
    vm.showStuff2 = true;
  });
}, 3000);
```

You could also consider using `$scope.$applyAsync()` which queues up expressions and functions for execution in the next digest cycle, as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope),

> `$applyAsync([exp]);`
>
> Schedule the invocation of $apply to occur at a later time. The actual time difference varies across browsers, but is typically around ~10 milliseconds.
>
> This can be used to queue up multiple expressions which need to be evaluated in the same digest.